# Function not returning what is expected, even when it appears to in debugger

Tags: python, unit-testing, debugging, return

Just a little background: This is for a STRIPS like program.
This test keeps returning false, even though it should be true. From what I can see in the debugger it should be true, and I can't see why it would be returning false.

[image]

Thanks for your help.
Debugger image:

World:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.logic = {}
    self.actions = {}
    self.goals = set()
    self.curr_state = set()
```

Testcase:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.world = World()

def testWorldis_true(self):
     pred = "on"
     params = ("A", "B")
     self.assertFalse(self.world.is_true(pred, params))
     self.world.logic[pred] = params
     self.assertTrue(self.world.is_true(pred, params))
```

OUTPUT:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: testWorldis_true (objorstrippertests.TestWorldFunctions)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".stripperAssignment\src\objorstrippertests.py", line 54, in testWorldis_true
    self.assertTrue(self.world.is_true(pred, params))
AssertionError: False is not true
```

Comment: You're going to have to give us more to work with than that.  How about some executable test code and a test case?

Comment: @KeithRandall added a bit, is that enough? Sorry for the lack of substance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
 self.world.logic[pred] = params
```

with:

```
 self.world.logic[pred] = set([params])
```

or even better (maintaining encapsulation!):

```
 self.world.set_true(pred, params)
```

`logic` is a map from a predicate to a set of parameter tuples, not a single parameter tuple.

Answer (score 1):

The test is actually working correctly:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['on'] = ('A','B')
>>> ('A','B') in d['on']
False
```

This is `False` because `('A','B')` is not in the tuple `('A','B')`. Each iteration over `('A','B')` will return `A` and `B`:

```
>>> for x in d['on']:
...    print x
... 
A
B
```

If you change your return to `==` then it will work correctly:

```
>>> d['on'] == ('A','B')
True
```